# Cannot open NetCDF File in QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf

I am trying to open a NetCDF file in QGIS. However it is not loading when I try to open it using Layer > Add Layer > Raster or even dragging and dropping it. I have also tried upgrading to master as suggested from this [thread](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20980).

Here is the error message for 3.4-Madeira and 3.10-A Coruna

```
Invalid Layer: Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, 
URI: C:/Users/~/Dec-Levels.nc
```

Here is the error message for 3.13.0-Master

```
Invalid Layer: Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: C:\Users\~\sa.nc 
(file: ..\..\..\src\core\raster\qgsrasterlayer.cpp row: 
618function QgsRasterLayer::setDataProvider:)
```

I am using Windows 10 64bit and used the 64bit installers for QGIS. I also used this example file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vtHc5GtDhUe2ENTkua8ihWqp6jYTHPBo

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the linked thread, QGIS (3.2+) can open the NetCDF file as a **mesh** layer.

(1) Open the file using `Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer`.

(2) By default, the first variable (Geopotential_level:250) will be plotted. Below is a short note to To view the variable you need.

1. Open the Layer Properties (by right-clicking on the `Dec-Levels` layer on the Layers panel).
2. On the Symbology tab, double click on the grey area at the right-hand-side  of the desired variable to change it to rainbow square. You can also change the date/time by a slidebar/pulldown menu.

[image]

3. Then click on [OK] or [Apply] button.

   [image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Comment: The current latest version of QGIS is 3.18 but the answer suggests using a 3.2+ version, how this is possible?

Comment: @gis The sub-version number of QGIS 3 increases in a style like: 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, ... ... 3.18, ...

Comment: I did exactly the same but getting error. Quick question: Do I need to first install a plugin or does it come preloaded? My QGIS version is `3.12.2-București` on `Windows 10`.

Comment: @PDash The function to build mesh layer (from NetCDF) is preloaded. What kind of error have you got?

Comment: @Kazuhito, thanks for getting back. It seems like an issue with `v3.12.2`. I installed the latest version `3.26.3-Buenos Aires` and it works with the preloaded option.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the nc file. I check it with gdalinfo (from gdal utilities):

```
gdalinfo Dec-Levels.nc 
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: Dec-Levels.nc
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#history=2018-12-10 17:18:38 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.9.2: grib_to_netcdf /data/data03/scratch/50/46/_mars-atls00-a562cefde8a29a7288fa0b8b7f9413f7-X9jE61.grib -o /data/data05/scratch/5e/f4/_grib2netcdf-atls18-70e05f9f8ba4e9d19932f1c45a7be8d8-eDzoQH.nc -utime
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":z
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[124x4x121x161] geopotential (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":t
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[124x4x121x161] air_temperature (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":q
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[124x4x121x161] specific_humidity (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":w
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[124x4x121x161] lagrangian_tendency_of_air_pressure (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":r
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[124x4x121x161] relative_humidity (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":u
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[124x4x121x161] eastward_wind (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=NETCDF:"Dec-Levels.nc":v
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[124x4x121x161] northward_wind (16-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

It looks OK. Then I load all layers (seven layers) into QGIS 3.12 without any error:

[image]

I suppose your file had some defect during downloading. Test the downloaded file with *gdalinfo* (you can start it for osgeo4w shell window). You should also check in case of error if your gdal version supports netCDF:

```
gdalinfo --formats
Supported Formats:
VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
DERIVED -raster- (ro): Derived datasets using VRT pixel functions
GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
... very log list ...
netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format
...
```

I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 Linux, gdal 2.2.3 and QGIS 3.12.1

Answer (score -1):

You can simply drag and drop the file in QGIS. It will automatically ask for the variable to be plotted. It worked for me.

Comment: OP already said that drag and drop didn't work.